# How to replace a string containing sqare brackets in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

how do you replace a string value with another in JavaScript ?

I have a string that contains a lot of this substring- `Items[0]`. How do I replace all of this to `Items[1]`, taking into account that '0' is a dynamic value that I get from a variable.

I have used the replace method, and tried some 'RegExp' but couldn't do that. I think its because of those square brackets:

```
str.replace(new RegExp("Items[" + j + "]", "g"), "Items[" + (j - 1) +"]"));
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @PraveenKumar, where should I append my variable ?

Comment: @Shanid In your code.

Comment: `str.replace(new RegExp("Items[" + j + "]", "g"), "Items[" + (j - 1) +"]"));`  here j is the variable which stores the index value

Comment: "*Where should you append [your] variable?*" - somewhere in the code that you haven't shown us would be my first guess. You have, as I write this, >300 rep; you should have an idea that showing your code is necessary for us to help you by now.

Comment: @Shanid: You were *really* close! (You should have included that in your question.) You just have to escape the `[`; I explain how in my answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas, Sorry, my bad. I was in a rush and in the middle of googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `new RegExp` to create the regular expression. In the regex, you have to use `\` to escape the `[` because otherwise it has a special meaning. Since you're going to have to use a string to create the regex (since you need to include the value of your variable), you **also** have to escape the `\` in the string, so we end up with two:

```js
var variable = 0;
var rex = new RegExp("\\[" + variable + "]", "g");
var str = "This has Item[0] in more than one Item[0] place.";
var str = str.replace(rex,   "Item[" + (variable + 1) + "]");
// If you want a dynamic replacement ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// In this case, I used the value plus one.
console.log(str);
```

The `"g"` is a flag meaning "global" (throughout the string, not just the first occurrence).

Comment: I tried with a single '\' earlier, I will try this now.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks, it works now. :)